# Populating related datasets from a table adapter

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm using table adapters and datasets in .NET (version 2.0).

I have two tables like this:

```
Table1
------
...
TypeId

Table2
------
Id
Name
```

where Table1.TypeId is linked to Table2.Id.

I've strongly generated these types by using the wizard so now I can do things like this:

```
Table1Adapter adapter = new Table1Adapter();
Table1DataSet data = adapter.GetData();

foreach(Table1Row row in data) { ... }
// Can now iterate through and display the data
```

This all works fine.  But now I also want the data from Table2.  I have noticed that in row there is generated field Table2Row which seems ideal but it is set to null.  How do I populate this dataset properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each DataTable in Typed-Dataset has its own TableAdapter. So you'll have to the same step for each DataTable in the dataset.

There does not exists any api that lets you do this auto-fill of the entire typed-dataset or no such code is generated within typed-dataset that supports this. It is also difficult to do this because TableAdapters do not have a common base-class that can let you do this.

If you really need to do this, you'll have to maintain a collection of DataTable type-names and TableAdapter type-names and iterate over the collection to perform the dataset fill.

So I recommend to fill dataset for each table in 'hard-code' manner.

Comment: Alright, and what is the best way to merge this data into my parent data table?

Comment: Create instances of each TableAdapter and fill the Dataset. You won't be to fill entire dataset at once, you must do it table-by-table.

Comment: So if I have two adapters and two datasets, how do I enforce the relationship?  I'd really like to do something like row.typerow.Name

Comment: Relationships will be enforced but you won't be able to access them relationally.

Comment: For anyone else passing this way, you can navigate relationaly around the tables in a dataset using the GetChildRows and GetParentRow methods. Also you can use expression-based columns for lookups into standing data etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a Microsoft Data Provider called `MSDataShape', which provides this functionality. It was flagged for depreciation last when I checked and I don't know what the current status and future plans are, or what replaces it.

Here's an example of a single "SQL command", that will return, I believe, a `DataSet` with two nicely related `DataTable`-s:

```
   SHAPE  {select * from customers}
   APPEND ({select * from orders} AS rsOrders
           RELATE customerid TO customerid)
```

Potential replacement to look at is well-crafted FOR XML query, but I have not played with that.

**EDIT:**
I think [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5338091/365968) does exactly that using XML.