# Read multiple tables with relations with t-sql into DataSet

Tags: .net, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dataset

Is it possible to `select data` with one `t-sql` statement from multiple tables (`join`) into a string representation and directly `insert` this text into a data set (`DataSet.ReadXml(...)`).

I need to preserve the relations, of course.

I have seen some complex examples using `FOR XML`, but is there a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I did it myself:

```
SQL = "SELECT table1.x, table2.z FROM table1 
       INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.SubID
       FOR XML AUTO, XMLDATA";
```

and

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = SQL;
data.ReadXml(((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)cmd).ExecuteXmlReader(),
               xmlReadMode.Fragment);
```

that's it